# Re-posting a question because the initial question wasn't detailed enough

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm wondering about something. I recently posted a question, [Counting number of times data appears in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502051/java-counting-number-of-times-data-appears-in-a-class). It has answers that work for the question itself, so I'm not going to delete it because it is very handy.

But I'm wondering if I can post essentially the same question, but with a different initial situation. I left out quite some important details in that I cannot edit the variables within the class, and that I can't use particular kinds of 'dynamic data structures such as arraylists'. The university apparently wants to make sure we can use only the basics to answer the problem if we have to.

I'm not sure if this is an okay thing or not though. I feel like editing the initial question would make the answers to it very cluttered since the answers that are there aren't ones I can use, but ARE ones that others wanting to know how to do that kind of thing can use.

Comment: For what's it's worth, you can't delete a question with an upvoted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are right in not wanting to invalidate any answers to the existing question, so posting a new question is really all you can do.

However, you will run the risk of getting closed as a duplicate if people can't see how your new question is sufficiently different. There's no easy answer to this, it's up to you to make it clear what the differences are.

Comment: Okay, thank-you! I'll definitely make sure to include all the information this time. I think it's definitely different enough to be worth the repost.